# Cannot access Admin after site was moved to new server

Tags: expressionengine

I am getting the error

An Error Was Encountered

Unable to load the requested class: Email

I can see the site OK.

This is an older version of EE.

I tried looking through the config files to see if there is anything that might need updating but couldn't find anything except pointing the site to the new server.